# Ionic Framework to customize the select button

Tags: android, ios, css, ionic-framework

Is it possible to override the ionic css for a select menu to display a custom dropdown arrow?

I have tried to do this here http://codepen.io/DevinGray/pen/gPxwvB

but it just puts the arrow over the original instead of replacing it

this is the styles that I tried

```
 .styled-select select {
   background: transparent;
   width: 268px;
   padding: 5px;
   font-size: 16px;
   line-height: 1;
   border: 0;
   border-radius: 0;
   height: 34px;
   -webkit-appearance: none;
   }

.styled-select {
    padding: 0 5px 0 0;
   overflow: hidden;
   background: url(http://rccgroseofsharon.co.za/images/more4.png) no-repeat right !important;
   border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change custom dropdown arrow color using this css.

```
.item-select::after{
    color:#FF0000;
}

.styled-select {
    background: none;
}
```